# Remove trailing /index.php from url using .htaccess

Tags: php, angular, .htaccess, angular8

I am building one angular app with PHP as the API server. I would like to clear the  trailing `/index.php` from the angular `post` method. I tried using `.htaccess` file like below

```
    ######### Begin - RewriteEngine enabled
    RewriteEngine On
    ########## End - RewriteEngine enabled

    ########## remove index.php from the end of URI
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
    ##########
```

My url structure is like below

```
http://localhost/api/auth/index.php
```

And I would like to access it like `http://localhost/api/auth`

Right now I am able to get the post data by using

```
this.http.post('/api/auth/', parameters, request.options)
```

But I don't want that `/` at the end of the url. How can I add this condition too in the `.htaccess` file? Any help could appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add `RewriteRule` that appends trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it location specific? Or can I add it at the end of the file?

Comment: Anywhere after `RewriteEngine On` statement would be fine.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working for me. I tried putting this immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` and after the current given condition. Not working in both cases

Comment: Is this for adding a trailing slash? I need to remove the slash at the end.